# Bamboo: Reuse same yml specs in multiple projects

Tags: git, yaml, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I'm using Atlassian Bamboo 7.1.1.
I'm creating pipelines as a code using YAML.
I have one git repository with a YAML specs to reuse in multiples pipelines. Let's call this repo: `common-specs`
Then, I have a repository per microservice.

My idea is to have one `bamboo-specs/bamboo.yml` in each microservice repo like this:

Microservice 1 repository:

```
---
version: 2
# ...
Build job: !include 'common/build-job.yml'
```

Where `build-job.yml` file comes from the `common-specs` repo.

So, I tried using git submodules (in each microservice repo) but I can't make it work.

The Bamboo error during specs scan is:

```
Cloning into /path/to/submodules ...
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: could note read from remote repository
```

When bamboo tries to clone the git submodule.

Notes:

- I'm using bamboo "linked repositories" using GIT with my SSH shared credentials (created by me before).
- I enabled submodules.
- The SSH key is the right one! I can clone it on my local.
- Just in case: I also put the same SSH key on the bamboo "Agent" and modified the `~/.ssh/config` to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I would give access of the repo A to Repo B in bamboo-specs rep permission config.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since the Bamboo Spec scanning happens on each Linked Repository, it may not be possible to have files from another repository consumed during the scanning process.